# Creating an Array by Replacing ints

Tags: java

I have to create an array that takes two ints and makes a new array with the same contents but the occurrences of value 1 are replaced with two. Can someone help me this is what I have so far.
 There is an error with the assertArrayEquals part.

```
public static replace(int[] in, int find, int replace) {
      for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
          if (in[i] == find) {
              in[i] = replace;
              return;
          }
      }
  }



 assertArrayEquals(new int[]{5, 5, 5, 5}, Array.replace(new int[]{5, 0, 0, 5}, 0, 5));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you please give more details? Given some example input, what output are you expecting?

Comment: I am having trouble producing a new array where the occurrences of value 1 are replaced with value 2

Comment: Don't return after the first match.

Comment: @laune i did that and it did not work

Comment: What do you mean "it did not work"? You cannot use the assertArrayEquals the way you do.

Comment: @EmmaL runs for me. check [here](http://ideone.com/R70rBE)

Comment: OK, modified your method to work either way, as a function returning the array reference and as a void function, just modifying the array object.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void replace(int[] in, int find, int replace) {
  for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
      if (in[i] == find) {
          in[i] = replace;
 //             do not return; continue to replace other elems
      }
  }
}
```

To test, use this:

```
int[] a =new int[]{5, 0, 0, 5};
Array.replace(a, 0, 5);
assertArrayEquals(new int[]{5, 5, 5, 5}, a );
```

It might be possible to use a function:

```
public int[] void replace(int[] in, int find, int replace) {
  for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
      if (in[i] == find) {
          in[i] = replace;
 //             do not return; continue to replace other elems
      }
  }
  return in;
}
```

And now this should work:

```
assertArrayEquals(new int[]{5, 5, 5, 5}, Array.replace(new int[]{5, 0, 0, 5}, 0, 5));
```

Comment: how do i continue to replace the elements?

Comment: Don't use "return;". You stay in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `return` statement

```
for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
      if (in[i] == find) {
          in[i] = replace;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning too early from this function:

```
for each value 'x' in the input array:
    if 'x' is equal to our 'find' value, replace it and return
```

The problem here is that as soon as you find one matching value, you replace it (good), but then you return (bad). If there are two or more matching values in the input array, this only replaces the first one. It's an easy fix though, just remove that return statement:

```
public static void replace(int[] in, int find, int replace) {
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        if (in[i] == find) {
            in[i] = replace;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove the `return;` line then the program will work fine. `return` will cause the method to stop immediately. Therefore, the reason why your code does not work is that the method just stops after checking the first item. And also, remember to add a return type of `int[]` to the method:

```
public static int[] replace(int[] in, int find, int replace) {
      for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
          if (in[i] == find) {
              in[i] = replace;
          }
      }
      return in;
}
```

However, here is an alternative solution with the new Stream API:

```
public static int[] replace(int[] in, int find, int replace) {
    return Arrays.stream(in).map(x -> x == find ? replace : x).toArray();
}
```